# issue in conversion of date using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am very new in python working on dates. I have 2 type of dates (because getting in array dynamically). Something like this  **['2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374' , '2021-03-18 08:29:36']**

I am trying to get these in this format  **17/02/2022 08:29 PM**.

Until now trying something like this:

```py
def update_date(datetime):
    date_formating = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
    return date_formating
```

but getting errors like:

`ValueError: time data '2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'`

I need a solution which can turn both formats I am getting into desired format. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If all of the different input formats are known, you can just use `Except ValueError` to skip one and move to the next format.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()` works on both of the 2 input formats.

Comment: Also, to convert a `datetime` to string, use `strftime`, not `strptime`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a list comprehension with [`datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_strs = ['2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374', '2021-03-18 08:29:36']
>>> [datetime.fromisoformat(s).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p') for s in date_strs]
['17/02/2022 08:29 AM', '18/03/2021 08:29 AM']
```

Comment: got this in input  2021-11-17 19:34:13.8934`   and getting this error     `ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2021-11-17 19:34:13.8934'`   it seems same string but giving issue :(((\

Comment: You'll have to make sure that the fractional seconds are either 3 or 6 digits

Comment: @FObersteiner is there any way to do this with function ?  or with some string concatenate funtions ?

Answer (score 1):

The times in the given list come in two different formats

1. with microseconds
2. with seconds (and no microseconds)

This code highlights the differences and would work:

```py
import datetime as dt

t = ['2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374' , '2021-03-18 08:29:36']

# format with microseconds
d1 = dt.datetime.strptime(t[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

# format with seconds
d2 = dt.datetime.strptime(t[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# format user wants
x = d1.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
y = d2.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
print(x)
print(y)
```

The result:

```
02/17/2022 08:29 AM
03/18/2021 08:29 AM
```